# Amazon ec2 regional data transfer

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I want to use free EC2 tiers , they provide 1 gb free for regional data transfer.I want to know what is regional data transfer.

For example , I access my website with public dns and it contains one php file.That gets the json from another source.Example is below.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("https://api.google.com/test.json");
```

So above code is called regional data transfer ? Or what is it.when will i get charged for regional data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Regional Data Transfer only applies for AWS services, so if you're transferring data from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance in the same AWS region it's free, if you're transferring data between EC2 instances in different regions you have to pay.

An AWS region is a grouping of Availability Zones, an Availability Zone being:

> Each availability zone runs on its own physically distinct, independent infrastructure, and is engineered to be highly reliable. Common points of failures like generators and cooling equipment are not shared across Availability Zones. Additionally, they are physically separate, such that even extremely uncommon disasters such as fires, tornados or flooding would only affect a single Availability Zone.

From https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/:

> *Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To:*
>
> - Amazon S3, Amazon Glacier, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon SES, Amazon SQS, or Amazon SimpleDB in the same AWS Region - *$0.00 per GB*
> - Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift or Amazon ElastiCache instances, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, or Elastic Network Interfaces in the same Availability Zone
>
>   - Using a private IP address - *$0.00 per GB*
>   - Using a public or Elastic IP address - *$0.01 per GB*
> - Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift or Amazon ElastiCache instances, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, or Elastic Network Interfaces in another Availability Zone or peered VPC in the same AWS Region - *$0.01 per GB*
>
>   - Another AWS Region - *$0.02 per GB*

[Amazon's pricing calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) is very handy for figuring out potential costs, and it shows free tier pricing too.